# Xcode crashing on playground error

Tags: xcode, xcode6, swift-playground

When I make an error in Xcode's playground feature, the whole app will close, with the problem report including the error; for example,

> `UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[DSAFastToken copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

I am running **Xcode 6.1.1** on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: What is the exact version of your Xcode ?

Comment: The exact version is 6.1.1.

Comment: DSAFastToken has purely to do with the documentation. I would suggest that you try deleting all your documentation (doc sets) and download them again. You may need to clean the Xcode caches as well.

Comment: If re-download still fails, consider to re-install Xcode.

Comment: I agree. No one has ever seen this error (a google search finds nothing at all), so it sounds like your Xcode installation is corrupt in some unique way.

Comment: Opening help also caused the application to crash. Removing the docs from the package seems to have fixed the problem.